# Any performance benefit to store md5(url) instead of url (used as keys)?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I have a MySQL table containing many urls, and I can store the url in its original form, or I can store it as a md5() value of it.

And I will set this to be an indexed column so I can select them faster.

I was wondering if using the md5 would have any performance benefit mostly considering the data will always have the same string size (32) vs storing the plain url where length would vary from 6 chars to 128 or more chars.

The length of the data is about the same, I selected 200 000 random records and I compared url vs md5(url) string size:

```
total_url_chars: 7085326
total_hash_chars: 6400000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**  Don't bother using md5.

**Long answer:**

- The complexity of your code, etc, should not be ignored.
- Fixed-length versus variable-length does not impact performance.
- MD5 would be "different" much sooner, usually within the first 5 characters.  A URL would usually have to go farther before finding a mismatch.  That is, the "compare" would be faster with md5.  I don't think this difference is significant enough to tip the scales.
- Packing the MD5 (`UNHEX(MD5(...))` -> `BINARY(16)` would shrink the footprint of the MD5.  But getting rid of the MD5 shrinks it further.
- If URLs can be too big to fit in an index, then something must be done.  (You say the limit is 128 characters?)
- Adding another column hurts performance of all queries by a *minor* amount.  (Again, this should not tip the scales.)